# How to monitor Android network performance?

Tags: android, performance-testing, android-testing, android-espresso, android-networking

We want to do network performance monitoring by monitoring the api calls. Currently we are using [Android Network](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-network.html) monitoring which is integrated with Android Studio.
There are some problem with this framework. It can only give the amount of data transfer and receive. It doesn't give the number of api call. This metrics is really necessary to determine if there is unnecessary api call. Otherwise it would be hard to determine.
It is integrated with the Android Studio and we can't use it in the test framework because it just gives the graph which is also hard to compare the result.

I want to know if there is any **framework** available which can be used to get different metrics of Network performance.

Comment: I am not sure, why this was down voted.. This is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there is a library for this provided by Facebook. Please check:

`network-connection-class`     [[facebook-code-site](https://code.facebook.com/projects/1547113495553528/network-connection-class/)]       [[github link](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class)]

Comment: Thanks you @SaravInferm for providing answer. After looking at the documentation, it looks like, it provides the information about the network connection but not the number of api calls. This is for production app I am looking for something which can be used for the test environments. I basically want to compare the number of api calls made for a scenario for different build so I can find the delta between them. This could be useful for identifying any unnecessary api call.s

Comment: So you want number of times api is being called right? then you can use analytics library to do that, (try google analytics | firebase analytics | crashlytics answers)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that can help you is Ixia's IxChariot.

IxChariot is a versatile product that is used for [testing network peformance](https://www.ixiacom.com/products-services/performance-monitoring) in various scenarios.

In your case, you can install the IxChariot endpoint on an Android device (download it from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ixia.ixchariot)) and use the endpoint to generate traffic to and from the device and measure its network performance, in a lab environment.

Additionally, you have to install a second endpoint on the IxChariot server hosted in a cloud or public network.

Both endpoints must be configured to connect to the Registration Server located on the same machine as the IxChariot server. Once this configuration is complete, you can use the web interface to run various tests on the mobile data connection.

The range of available tests includes TCP, UDP, RTP, and VoIP traffic, with unlimited or configurable data rates. The reported statistics include Throughput, One-Way Delay, Jitter, Loss Rate, and MOS Score. IxChariot is capable of sending bidirectional test traffic, thus testing both the inbound and outbound directions of the mobile data connection.

Full disclosure - I work as Sr. Marketing Engineer at Ixia.